# como armar un metodo toString que imprima un string a partir de pasar un arreglo de enteros?

Tags: java, array, string

la consigna seria:
Hacer un método toString que pasándole un arreglo de ints arme un String de la siguiente forma
{5, 3, 8, 1} y lo retorne.

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el array con un `for` e ir almacenando tus datos una variable `String`.

De tal forma que la variable `String` la vas actualizando con cada vuelta que de el bucle y al final haces un `return` de dicha variable.

```
public class lista {
    int lista[]={5, 3, 8, 1};

    public lista(){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //esta variable va a ser la encargada de ir apuntando tus números del array
        String res="";

            //recorres la lista y en cada vuelta añades un numero de la lista a la variable res
            for(int i = 0; i<lista.length; i++){
                res+=lista[i]+" ";
            }
            
            //finalmente solo tienes que retornar res
            return res;
    }
}
```

Por ultimo, al aplicar el método `toString` a un objeto, saldrá por pantalla: 5 3 8 1